# Habtm attributes with active record import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bulkinsert, bulkupdate, activerecord-import

Is there any way to save `HABTM` associations along with the records using `Active Record Import`?
I saw some posts suggesting to use `has many / has_many through` instead. But it would be great if I can maintain the current structure.

I couldn't find a solution with `Bulk Insert` gem also.